# Squid Proxy let user use only one ip

Tags: proxy, squid, squidguard

how can i let user1 only use  `100.160.238.0:17648`  and user2 only use `100.160.238.1:48049`  and user3 only use `100.160.238.2:26394` ??? I tried some method but not work now my config is mixed with error. So please if anyone know how to do this then please help me. i tried below method but some error in my config.

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
#external_acl_type ip_user %SRC %LOGIN /usr/lib/squid/ip_user_check -f /etc/squid/ip.conf
#external_acl_type ip_user %SRC %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_file_userip_acl -f /etc/squid/ip.conf
```

if anyone know solution then please share your config or sample please.

OS CENTOS 7 X64BIT.

Answer (score 0):

```
acl user1 src 192.168.0.2/32
acl user2 src 192.168.0.3/32
acl user3 src 192.128.0.4/32

acl desPort1 port 17648
acl desPort2 port 48049
acl desPort3 port 26394

acl destIp1 dst 100.160.238.0/32
acl destIp2 dst 100.160.238.1/32
acl destIp3 dst 100.160.238.2/32

http_access allow desPort1 destIp1
http_access allow desPort2 destIp2
http_access allow desPort3 destIp3
http_access deny all

http_port 3128
```

I believe this would allow;

- user1 access to destination 100.160.238.0:17648 via proxy:3128
- user2 access to destination 100.160.238.1:48049 via proxy:3128
- user3 access to destination 100.160.238.2:26394 via proxy:3128

(The acls are always "or" logic, so for multiple acls / "and" logic, the limit needs imposing on the access line).

Otherwise setup multiple daemons.

UPDATE:

```
http_access allow desPort1 destIp1 !desPort2 !destIp2 !desPort3 !destIp3
http_access allow desPort2 destIp2 !desPort1 !destIp1 !desPort3 !destIp3
http_access allow desPort3 destIp3 !desPort1 !destIp1 !desPort2 !destIp2
```

Comment: your solution does not work user2 and user3 also access user1 ip.

Comment: http_access allow desPort1 destIp1 !desPort2 !destIp2 (and so on)

Comment: does not work this UPDATE. do you know any method which proxy provider using for login? because they provide same login function each user login and use only allowed ips.